# Angular 2 *ngIf not updating the HTML template

Tags: angular

Why is the *ngIf not updating the template? The title hello is always shown irrespective of the fact that isVisible changes to false after 2 seconds.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',

  template: `
    <h1 *ngIf="isVisible == true">{{title}}</h1>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Hello!';
  isVisible = true;

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(function() {
            this.isVisible = false;
            console.log(this.isVisible);
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With anonymous function like this one

```javascript
setTimeout(function() {
   this.isVisible = false;
}, 2000);
```

execution context (`this`) is pointing to global object (`window`), however you want it to be `AppComponent` instance. In this cases you would better use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which preserve lexical scope:

```javascript
constructor() {
  setTimeout(() => {
     this.isVisible = false;
  }, 2000);
}
```

There are alternative approaches you could use, such as binding context with [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and saving context reference, but arrow-functions are the most convenient in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the == true.

Ngif compares by default the expression to true.

Comment: What you are saying is correct, because ngIf will check for a truthy statement, but that won't solve the problem OP is having though.